# find the last 4 dgits of $2^{2016}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am trying to find the last 4 digits of $2^{2016}$.

Here is where I am up to:

2^2016 = x mod 10000

2^2016 = x mod 625 - I used Eulers function to find that 2^16 = 1 mod 625 = 536

2^2016 = x mod 16

Now I am stuck. The second equation can not use Euler so how do I continue?

Thanks

Comment: $2^n$ is a multiple of $16$ whenever $n\ge4$.

Comment: Thanks for that but how does that help me? Don't I need to somehow use the chinese remaindor theorem to solve the 2 equations? I am just not sure as to how.

Comment: You know the remainders modulo $625$ and $16$. They are $536$ (aassuming you did it correctly) and $0$. What's stopping you?

Comment: probably brain freeze. Does it make sense to continue as follows?
x=0(mod16)
x=536(mod625) and then solve for x?

Comment: yes, you could use the Chinese remainder theorem

Comment: Note $\bmod 4\!:\ 2^{\large 2}\equiv 0\Rightarrow 2^N\equiv 2^{N\large \bmod\!2}\,$ by modular order reduction. Now you can apply CRT, but it's easier to use the [mod distributive law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242), e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2410186/242), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890456/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3212901/242). $\ \ $

Answer (score -1):

$2^{2016} = 16 \times 2^{2012} \equiv 0 \mod{16}$.